# ARM (v7) unaligned access handling and Device/Strongly-ordered memory

Tags: arm, memory-alignment, armv7

ARMv7's `LDR` (and some others) instruction is supporting unaligned addresses to load from by "breaking down" the access to multiple aligned accesses (as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@iLevex/the-curious-case-of-unaligned-access-on-arm-5dd0ebe24965) for example).
On the other hand if the memory is mapped as Device or Strongly-ordered, then unaligned accesses are not permitted (will trigger exception).
My question is about the rationale of such a behavior. After all the access can be broken down to multiple aligned for these memory types as well. Here is my guess:

1. Device memory is usually used for mapping hardware registers, so each access might have a side effect. So the architecture does not permit "hidden" accesses which might have unwanted side-effects
2. Strongly ordered memory is assuming strict access ordering, so "hidden" accesses will come out of the expected order.

So these two are my speculated rationales from the "expected behavior violation" point of view. Are there any others which are physical limitations?

The bottom-line rationale for my question is that we have some memory-mapped region which has alignment requirements on a physical level, but I don't care about any of the considerations I listed in a question and is fine if ARM is rearranging or breaking down the accesses. So my doubt is whether there is any issue I am missing that might arise if I map it as "Normal memory" (never cached).

Comment: ARM documents cacheable memory access as idempotent, so "breaking down" the unaligned access into multiple accesses is a lot more palatable for cacheable access than for device or strongly ordered memory. I'd say your point 1 is the most relevant.

Comment: @EOF Yeah, caching is another aspect that I omitted as it is not very relevant to my specific problem.. The rationale for my question is that we have some memory-mapped region which does have alignment requirements on a physical level, but I don't care about any of the considerations I listed in a question and is fine if ARM is rearranging or breaking down the accesses. So my doubt is whether there is any issue I am missing that might arise if I map it as "Normal memory".

Comment: Why don't you ask *that* question then, instead of this roundabout waffling?

Comment: @EOF I believe this part of research is important by itself. But I will add this part to the question.

Comment: It is not possible at least on the axi bus I am familiar with and we can all go read the docs, to do these unaligned accesses without breaking them into multiples.  Even if you have an stm of four words that are not double word aligned for a 64 bit axi will turn in to three transfers (This the whole align your stack on a 64 bit boundary thing) a word, a double word and a word.  At least for writes.  same for say a 64 bit value that is at address 0x1001, one transfer for the odd byte then another for the rest since they are within different words/doublewords on the other end and need separate..

Comment: ..byte lane enables

Comment: the one I am most famiiar with at no time will do a write with more than two doublewords, an 8 word/register stm for example gets broken into two transfers even when aligned.  reads on the other hand sure you could technically do a byte off 0x1001 32 bit read and do a length of one or two on the bus just like any read and then extract the bytes of interest and discard the rest.

Comment: multiple transactions are multiple transactions could check the docs, but I would assume they are separate even if tied to the same instruction which means other transactions could get in the middle at some point, maybe not on the write address bus but on the write data bus depending on the chip vendors controller and what is going on at that moment, distance (clocks) to the targets, a split up transfer would have the handful of clock overhead anyway but if it is two or three clocks further than something else that came after, that can get in the way and if for some reason that...

Comment: ...is the same address...

Comment: stuff to ponder, ARMs docs are pretty good but I dont think they are that good.  I know at least they have had inconsistent documentation that lead to software and chip issues.  Sometimes though the axi/amba docs can clarify things, in this case if they still offer an l2 cache controller that may clear things up.

Comment: before they did this an unaligned, say on an arvm4t/ARM7TDMI, it would rotate which you could use to your advantage perhaps, although arm has a good barrel shifter.  so if you had 0x12345678 at 0x1000 and did a word read at 0x1001 you would get 0x78123456 kind of a thing, if you disabled the trap (if you could disable the trap, etc).  Your article indicates armv6 is when they started to support it by making multiple transfers as needed and that sounds about right.

Comment: I would also assume that device means it is peripheral control registers and other device memory and ideally wants to be not cached, but the code is aligned.

Comment: I hope you are not doing this so you can point structures across compile domains or other reasons for unaligned transfers that are easily fixed in software by simply never generating them.

Comment: @old_timer This is done for plain binary access to a memory mapped storage device. The main operation to be performed is `memcpy`, which is unfortunately not implemented with alignment considerations.